# Javascript game, collision detection when hitting a wall

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I've been following W3schools tutorial on creating a JavaScript game in a canvas https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_obstacles.asp

I've got to the stage where they add an obstacle in. Currently, it has collision detection which stops the game when it hits the wall. I am trying to figure out a way to treat it like a wall where the box could hit it and no longer move that direction and continue the game, making the wall work.

Heres what I've got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/j9cy1mne/1/

```
<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacle;

    var speed = 3;

    function startGame() {
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
      myObstacle = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);
      myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      },
      stop: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;

        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
          crash = false;

        }


        return crash;
      }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
        console.log("crash");
      } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myObstacle.update();
        myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
        myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
        myGamePiece.update();
      }
    }
    document.onkeydown = checkKeyD;

    function checkKeyD(e) {

      e = e || window.event;

      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
        myGamePiece.speedY = -speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
        myGamePiece.speedY = speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        // left arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = -speed;
      } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right arrow
        myGamePiece.speedX = speed;
      }

    }

    document.onkeyup = clearmove;

    function clearmove() {
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
    }

  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have part of it finished. You just need to have the crash code in the if statement for moving the player right. This will run the code only when the player is pressing the right arrow.

`else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
  // right arrow
  // add crash code here
  myGamePiece.speedX = speed;
}`

Comment: I did attempt this, unfortunately when I hold down the right key sometimes it goes through the wall

Answer (score 0):

Your game loop only executes when there is no crash:

```
function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    console.log("crash");
  } else {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
    myGamePiece.update();
  }
}
```

What you want to do is to set the `myGamePiece.speedX` and `myGamePiece.speedX` to `0` when a collision is detected. Something like:

```
function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myObstacle.update();
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  }
  myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
  myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
  myGamePiece.update();
}
```

Edit: You probably want to apply some code to "back up" when a collision is detected, so the pieces are no longer in a collided state